# Using Python to access JSON Dictionary from IMDB

Tags: javascript, python, html, json

Using this link:

https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7286456/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0

I am trying to access the JSON Dictionary Tag to determine if the video is a movie or not

This is the information I am after:

`` "`@type": "Movie", ``

In this JSON Code:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Movie",
  "url": "/title/tt7286456/",
  "name": "Joker",
  "image": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNGVjNWI4ZGUtNzE0MS00YTJmLWE0ZDctN2ZiYTk2YmI3NTYyXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTkxNjUyNQ@@._V1_.jpg",
  "genre": [
    "Crime",
    "Drama",
    "Thriller"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: if you have it as string then `if '"@type": "Movie"' in text:`

Comment: Please show the code which you have tried